# Using bluemix delivery pipeline across organizations and regions

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, delivery-pipeline

In Bluemix, I have to deploy exactly same application in different regions (UK & US-South). Is there a way I can use a single instance of delivery pipeline to deploy to different spaces in each of those regions. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

You can add three different Deploy Jobs (or three different stages with a single Deploy Job), each of one pointing to each region executing the same script.